# Estou tentando usar o .split() em uma def e nao sei porque nao esta dando certo alguem pode me ajudar?

Tags: python, tkinter, split

Estou tentando montar um simples script de sorteio usando a biblioteca Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
def sorteio():
    from random import choice
    nomes = (ed1.get)
    splitn = nomes.split(" ")
    sort = choice(splitn)
    lb3['text'] = '\033[34mO nome sorteado foi \033[31m{}'.format(sort.title())
janela = Tk()
ed1 = Entry(janela, width=50, bg='green')
bt1 = Button(janela, width=7, bg='green', command=sorteio, text='Sortear')
lb1 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='Digite no campo a baixo\nos nomes a serem sorteados')
lb2 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='Nomes:')
lb3 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='')
ed1.grid(row=2, column=2)
bt1.grid(row=3, column=2)
lb1.grid(row=1, column=2)
lb2.grid(row=2, column=1)
lb3.grid(row=4, column=2)
janela['bg'] = 'green'
janela.geometry('500x500+500+500')
janela.mainloop()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como voces podem ver, a função split não funcionou, e eu não sei de que outra forma eu posso converter a str em lista, se algm souber como me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato.

> Eu sou novato em programação então eu não sei muito bem como é o nome de cada coisa, então desculpa se eu errei algo aí...

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações Eric Verschoor,

Fiz alguns ajustes no método sorteio. Segue as linhas que foram modificadas e ao lado delas está um comentário para você comparar como estava antes das minhas alterações.

```
nomes = str(ed1.get()) # nomes = (ed1.get)
splitn = nomes.split(" ") # splitn = nomes.split()
sort = choice(splitn) # não alterei
lb3['text'] = 'O nome sorteado foi: ' + sort.title() # simplifiquei
```

Segue o código completo:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice    

def sorteio():    
    nomes = str(ed1.get())
    splitn = nomes.split()
    sort = choice(splitn)
    lb3['text'] = 'O nome sorteado foi: ' + sort.title()

janela = Tk()

ed1 = Entry(janela, width=50, bg='green')
bt1 = Button(janela, width=7, bg='green', command=sorteio, text='Sortear')
lb1 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='Digite no campo a baixo\nos nomes a serem sorteados')
lb2 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='Nomes:')
lb3 = Label(janela, bg='green', text='')

ed1.grid(row=2, column=2)
bt1.grid(row=3, column=2)
lb1.grid(row=1, column=2)
lb2.grid(row=2, column=1)
lb3.grid(row=4, column=2)

janela['bg'] = 'green'
janela.geometry('500x500+500+500')
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, ajudou mt, de pouquinho em pouquinho ou vou diminuindo meus erros. Tmj irmão

Comment: Que legal Eric, quando precisar de ajuda estou a disposição. Aqui nesta comunidade da para aprender muito coisa todos os dias!